# ACF Taxonomy: get ACF field from a post's terms

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I've built a site with custom taxonomies for different project types.

I use these taxonomy terms all over the site, including constructing default, generic titles for projects.

Example:

**Project**

- Project Style: Bright
- Project Type: Kitchen

I use these terms to generate a default title: "A Bright Kitchen"

===

I ended up adding an ACF Taxonomy Field as some of the plural terms were weird — porches vs porch, remodeling vs remodel, etc.

I've successfully pulled this field into my "auto name generating" code, but I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

```
<?php $project_types = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'project_type' );
if ( ! empty( $project_types ) ) {
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $project_types ) ) {

            foreach( $project_types as $term ) {
                $singular = get_field('singular', 'project_type_' . esc_html( $term->term_id ));

            }

    }
} ?>

<?php echo $singular ?>
```

How can I simplify / improve this code?

Comment: Beside the fact that you overwrite `$singular` in every loop step, I don't see any opportunity to shorten your code.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks!